How to Implement Direct Username and Password Login with Azure AD B2C in Flutter without Using Microsoft's UI?
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to implement a custom login screen that directly uses a username and password for authentication with Azure AD B2C, bypassing the default Microsoft login UI. The goal is to allow users to input their credentials directly into our app's interface.
Problem
However, when trying to acquire tokens using the Resource Owner Password Credential (ROPC) flow, I'm encountering a 404 error. Here is the code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _login() async {
    final String b2cTenantName = 'XXXXtest'; // Replace with your B2C tenant name
    final String userFlowName = 'B2C_1_ROPC_Auth'; // Replace with your User Flow name
    final String clientId = '14096713-1c23-XXXX-8284-XXf2b6a5e22e'; // Replace with your App ID
    final String scope = 'openid offline_access $clientId';
    final String username = _usernameController.text;
    final String password = _passwordController.text;

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://$b2cTenantName.b2clogin.com/$b2cTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/$userFlowName/oauth2/v2.0/token'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: {
          'client_id': clientId,
          'grant_type': 'password',
          'scope': scope,
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
          'response_type': 'token id_token'
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        print('response.statusCode  ${response.statusCode}');
        print('response.body  ${response.body}');
        _showDialog('Login Successful', 'Access Token: ${data['access_token']}');
      } else {
        print('response.statusCode  ${response.statusCode}');
        _showDialog('Login Failed', 'Failed to log in. Please check your credentials and try again.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('response.e   ${e}');
      _showDialog('Login Error', 'An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  void _showDialog(String title, String content) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(content),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _usernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

I've tried many approaches and even used code from Stack Overflow, but nothing has worked. Please help me if you know the solution. "
A new attempt: Here are the steps I followed.

I get client id from here


The user flow name is the same as the one you added.

b2cTenantName

domain name in here


when run flutter web show this error

and when run on android show this error

I/flutter (15894): response.statusCode  404

and I created the user here.

I tried all these steps. Please let me know if I made any mistakes.
NEW ERROR

I tried in postman also

App registrations



user flow

create user flow





Could you confirm whether your requirement is to generate access token without user interaction? What account type you selected while creating app registration in B2C tenant?

Yes, my requirement is for users to manually input their email and password directly into the app's login form. If the credentials are correct, the app should log them in by generating an access token. The app registration in the Azure B2C tenant has been set up to allow this. Specifically, I am looking for a way to implement this using a direct username and password authentication flow, which bypasses any external UI components for login.

Please check below answer and let me know if it works : )

Sure , and thank you so much for support

The XMLHttpRequest error you are seeing states clearly that the issue is CN invalid. Have you tried requesting the same URL with a browser or Postman to diagnose the certificate issue?

I'm not sure why you aren't trying for an OIDC set-up - delegating (/effectively 'federating') the authentication process.  And maybe with a JScript 'BackChannel' to communicate things back if need be.  Beware for B2C, the email might come across as an 'emails' (named) array-based claim rather than a scalar/single value 'email' claim.

@RichardHeap i updated the  question  with postman image

@DennisVM-D2i Currently, I am using a direct ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credential) flow for specific reasons, primarily due to the nature of our application which requires a non-interactive authentication process. However, I understand the security implications and the limitations associated with this approach.

Could you provide more details on setting up a secure 'BackChannel' as you mentioned, or any resources that could guide me in transitioning to an OIDC setup while still meeting my application's requirements? Also, regarding the 'emails' claim handling, are there specific practices you'd recommend ensuring smooth integration?

Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code in my environment like this:

To resolve the error, follow these steps where I registered one Azure AD B2C application with below account type that supports user flows:

While using ROPC flow, make sure to enable public client flow option in Authentication tab of application:

In App registration's Manifest, enable enableAccessTokenIssuance attribute to true like this:

Now, create one resource owner user flow in your Azure AD B2C tenant like this:


Now, I used below modified code in my environment that asked user to enter credentials and gave access token successfully like this:
main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _login() async {
    final String b2cTenantName = 'infrab2c'; // Replace with your B2C tenant name
    final String userFlowName = 'B2C_1_ROPC_Auth'; // Replace with your User Flow name
    final String clientId = '7983c484-db70-xxx-bc71-xxxxx'; // Replace with your App ID
    final String scope = 'openid offline_access $clientId';
    final String username = _usernameController.text;
    final String password = _passwordController.text;

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://$b2cTenantName.b2clogin.com/$b2cTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/$userFlowName/oauth2/v2.0/token'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: {
          'client_id': clientId,
          'grant_type': 'password',
          'scope': scope,
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
          'response_type': 'token id_token'
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        print('response.statusCode  ${response.statusCode}');
        print('response.body  ${response.body}');
        _showDialog('Login Successful', 'Access Token: ${data['access_token']}');
      } else {
        print('response.statusCode  ${response.statusCode}');
        _showDialog('Login Failed', 'Failed to log in. Please check your credentials and try again.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('response.e   ${e}');
      _showDialog('Login Error', 'An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  void _showDialog(String title, String content) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(content),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _usernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

Response:

Reference:
Set up a resource owner password credentials flow - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft

Thank you so much for your support. I tried your method and code multiple times, but it didn't work. Additionally, I encountered different errors on Android and web platforms. I updated my question with the new error details. If you can identify the issue, please help me.

I observed you are adding b2cTenantName = 'yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com'. Please remove .onmicrosoft.com part from b2cTenantName variable. Give only it's prefix which in infrab2c in my case.

I tried but still  display "response.statusCode  404"

Can you edit your question and add your current code in it?

Yes , i edited the question

Have you enabled public client flow option and manifest file of app registration? Please include those images too

yes, i added the images

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

i added user flow create steps
